# change opacity after 200ms in component style ReactJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I using ReactJS framework and I try that, this component to change its style after 200ms from `opacity 0` to `opacity 1`. Is it possible to do such a setTimeout?

```
<GreetingHeadline styles={?} id={this.props.user.id} />
```

Comment: @Andy, I would like to use opacity.

Comment: @Andy, but I don't have a transition. I want to, that this component is opacity 1 after 200ms.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example that uses toggles between hidden/visible classes. I've added the transition so the effect can be more easily seen (200ms is a very short time) but you can remove it in your code.

```js
class Test extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { classes: 'hidden' };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => this.setState({ classes: 'visible' }), 200);
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.state;
    return <div className={classes}>Text to be rendered</div>;
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```css
.hidden { opacity: 0; }
.visible { opacity: 1; transition: opacity 1s linear;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a variable to the state of the GreetingHeadline's parent component:

```
constructor() {
  this.state = {
    transparent: true;
  }
}
```

Then you can use setTimeout in the componentDidMount lifetime's method:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setTimeout(() => {
    this.setState({ transparent: false });
  }, 200);
}
```

Finally you can use variable from the state within your GreetingHeadline component's props:

```
<GreetingHeadline
  styles={{ opacity: this.state.transparent ? '0.7' : '1' }}
  id={this.props.user.id}
/>
```

Comment: Be careful when using snippets, you may want to test them before posting

Answer (score 0):

Setting a class is the easiest way to change the opacity.  Here's an example that also uses an animation to "smooth" the transition.

https://codesandbox.io/s/j371123nq9